# QGIS not responding

Tags: qgis

I've been working with QGIS 2.14.18 on my Win 7 64bit computer and ever since i tried updating to 2.18.12 i've had the problem that QGIS responds very slowly even if i'm not processing anything. Even just hovering over the tabs and tools takes quite a few seconds until you can see the mouseover effect. Sometimes it even says "(not responding)" in the title bar.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling version 2.14.18 but the same problem occurs. I've also tried to install it on different drives on my computer (C: and D: drive).
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?